# DataAnnotations tryvalidateobject always returns true

Tags: c#, data-annotations

```
namespace ClassValidation
{
    public class Student
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
        public String Firstname;


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        public String personalEmail;


            }
}


private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Student student = new Student();
            student.personalEmail = "del";


            ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(student, null, null);
            List<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            bool valid = Validator.TryValidateObject(student, context, results, true);

            if (!valid)
            {
                foreach (ValidationResult vr in results)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Write("   ::  {0}{1}", vr.ErrorMessage, Environment.NewLine);

                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The validator ignores the `[RequiredAttribute]` on fields - it takes into an account only properties; so for purposes of `Validator.Validate` - change your class to:

```
public class Student
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
  public String Firstname { get; set; }


  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
  public String personalEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is not technically correct, the `RequiredAttribute` is more than capable of working on fields as you can see from the definition `[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Property|AttributeTargets.Field|AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]`. It's the validator itself that ignores the fields during validation.

Answer (score 4):

If you dig into the validator source you will notice that `TryValidateObject` will only validate *properties*, not fields. More specifically, you will notice it's use of [GetObjectPropertyValidationErrors](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/Validator.cs,adab2e90a60e5923,references) (which omits fields).

I see no real reason for you to be using public fields here anyway therefore the simplest fix is to use properties

```
public class Student
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMEssage = "Email is required")]
    public string PersonalEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks james and ondrej  how could i miss that , thanks a lot!!

Comment: I converted my public fields to properties and I am still not getting validation errors when properties marked as required are null. I am wondering what else might be short-circuiting the validation. The check is being hit, but the result is always true (valid).

Comment: I just had another theory. I am using decimal and bool and etc--not decimal? and bool? and so forth. Since non-nullable decimals are always 0 and not null, could that be tricking the validation?

Comment: @JoeyMorgan I'm not sure I understand your setup, could you create a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) to demonstrate?