# ModelState.IsValid is always true while using Data annotation, MVC as Web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc, data-annotations, modelstate

I have seen many questions like this one but no answer has solved my problem.
I can submit a name that contains a space, or leaving a description field empty and the ModelState is still valid.

in my StartUp.cs I do use

```
services.AddMvc();
```

I did try without the Validator.TryValidateObject, and the Model.State is always valid.

my class has data annotation

```
public class UpdateAttributeResource
    {
        [Required, MaxLength(96), RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z0-9~_$\-]*$")]
        public string Name;
        [Required, MaxLength(96)]
        public string DisplayName;
        [Required, MaxLength(160)]
        public string DescriptionEn;
        [Required, MaxLength(160)]
        public string DescriptionFr;
        public string Comments;
    }
```

my controller receives a collection of my class and even when forcing validation using TryValidateObject the ModelState is still valid

```
public IActionResult UpdateAttributes([FromBody]UpdateAttributeResource[] updateAttributes)
{
    var validationContext = new ValidationContext(updateAttributes[0], null, null);
    var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

    var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(updateAttributes[0], validationContext, validationResults, true);

    if (!isValid)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("NOPE", "Nope");
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
```

Comment: Calling `TryValidateObject` doesn't affect `ModelState` so it is expected that `ModelState` would still be valid after calling it. You may have already, but as a troubleshooting step, I would double check that the values that should be failing validation are what's actually set on your `updateAttributes` model(s) _and_, more importantly, they are the values in the `ModelState` collection. In other words, verify the fields you're entering client-side are what's coming through server-side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually finally found the answer here 
[DataAnnotations tryvalidateobject always returns true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743595/dataannotations-tryvalidateobject-always-returns-true)

I don't know why it did not pop up before, anyway

> The validator ignores the [RequiredAttribute] on fields - it takes
>   into an account only properties;

So I simply needed to change my class to

```
public class UpdateAttributeResource
    {
        [Required, MaxLength(96), RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z0-9~_$\-]*$")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required, MaxLength(96)]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        [Required, MaxLength(160)]
        public string DescriptionEn { get; set; }
        [Required, MaxLength(160)]
        public string DescriptionFr { get; set; }
        public string Comments;
    }
```

Comment: Take it a s a rule - most tooling only works on properties. Some Validation methods and parameters also have it in their name.

Comment: Just cost me an hour of my life. Moreover, because implicit validation based on types does work properly.